# listactivity doesnt respond the onlistitemclick event?

Tags: android, android-layout

below is my code for listactivity can anyone tell me how can i get the event for an item click?

```
public class MyCustomListView extends ListActivity
{
    private ArrayList<String> m_orders=null;
    private ArrayList<String> artistsList=new ArrayList<String>();
    private OrderAdapter m_adapter;
    String[] array;
    String[] artists;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Intent intent=getIntent();
        array=intent.getStringArrayExtra("trackname");
        artists=intent.getStringArrayExtra("artists");
        m_orders = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            m_orders.add(array[i]);
            artistsList.add(artists[i]);
        }
        this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_orders);
                setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
    }
    private class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private ArrayList<String> items;
        public OrderAdapter(Context context,int id,ArrayList<String> items)
        {
            super();
            this.items=items;
        }

        public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view=convertView;
            if(view==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
            }
            String string=items.get(position);
            if(string!=null)
            {
                TextView t1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView t2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                if(t1!=null)
                {
                    t1.setText(items.get(position));
                }
                if(t2!=null)
                {
                    String artistName=artistsList.get(position);
                    if(artistName.equals(""))
                    {
                        t2.setText("UnKnown");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        t2.setText(artistName);
                    }

                }
            }
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return array.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
          Log.i("Position",""+arg2);        
    }
```

what is the wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

the code below solved my problem\;

```
 private class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener
    {
        private ArrayList<String> items;
        public OrderAdapter(Context context,int id,ArrayList<String> items)
        {
            super();
            this.items=items;
        }

        public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view=convertView;
            if(view==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
            }
            String string=items.get(position);
            if(string!=null)
            {
                TextView t1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView t2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                if(t1!=null)
                {
                    t1.setText(items.get(position));
                }
                if(t2!=null)
                {
                    String artistName=artistsList.get(position);
                    if(artistName.equals(""))
                    {
                        t2.setText("UnKnown");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        t2.setText(artistName);
                    }

                }
                view.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
            }
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return array.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.i("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@","buttonClicked");
        }
        }
    private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener
    {                    
        private int mPosition;         
        OnItemClickListener(int position)
        {                 mPosition = position;         }      
        @Override         
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {                 
            Log.v("****************", "onItemClick at position" + mPosition);                               }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initial code snippet you forgot to set the OnItemClickListener - in the answer to yourself you are setting it with  `view.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));`

If I understand it correctly, you are creating and setting it on each cell - it may make more sense to do it at the level of the ListView itself and only once. That should be better for performance and memory consumption ( `new OnItemClickListenr()` will each time create a new instance.)